# OnLongItemClickListener en un recyclerview

Tags: android-fragment, recyclerview

Muy buenas tardes, estoy con mi implementación del recycleview con sus opciones de eliminar y convertir a PDF una vez seleccionadas las imágenes que hay guardadas en dicha lista. Me gustaría hacer como he visto en las aplicaciones normalmente de cuando mantienes pulsado un item del recyclerview aparecen más opciones a realizar sobre ese item o items depende de los que se haya seleccionado. Mi idea es esa pero solamente para eliminar y convertir PDF esas imágenes. Solamente me gustaría saber como haria para hacer aparecer los items del menú, donde vienen las opciones de eliminar y convertir a PDF cuando mantenga pulsado un item del recyclerview y desaparezca cuando se retroceda hacia atras.

Esta es una idea clara de lo que tengo

[image: Esta es la imagen de referencia para que sepan a lo que me refiero]

Mi idea es como la mencioné anteriormente, mantengo pulsado una imagen y deben de aparecer las dos opciones de eliminar y convertir a PDF y cuando retrocedo desaparecen dichas opciones

Por el momento tengo implementado este código con el evento setOnLongClickListener en el adapter del recyclerview

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderImage holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

```
    ModelImage modelImage = imageArrayList.get(position);

    Uri imageUri = modelImage.getImageUri();

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(imageUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.icon_image)
            .into(holder.imageView);

    holder.setData(imageArrayList.get(position));
    holder.checkBox.isChecked();

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            return false;
        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            rvListenerImage.onImageClick(modelImage, position);
        }
    });

    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            modelImage.setChecked(isChecked);
        }
    });
}
```

Y esto lo que tengo implementado en el ImageListFragment donde tengo la lista de imágenes

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if(itemId == R.id.images_item_delete) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Eliminar imagenes")
                .setMessage("¿Seguro que quieres eliminar todas/solo imágenes seleccionadas?")
                .setPositiveButton("Eliminar todo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Eliminar todas las imágenes de la lista
                        eliminarImagenes(true);
                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton("Eliminar seleccionada", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Eliminar sólo las imágenes selecionadas
                        eliminarImagenes(false);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Cancelar la acción de eliminar las imágenes, cuadro de diálogo
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    } else if (itemId == R.id.lista_imagenes_pdf) {
        // Se muestra una lista con las imágenes seleccionadas para convertir a PDF
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Convertir a PDF").setMessage("Comvertir todas/imágenes seleccionadas a PDF")
                .setPositiveButton("Convertir a PDF", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Convertir todas las imágenes seleccionadas
                        convertirAPDF(true);
                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton("Convertir seleccionada", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Convertir sólo las imágenes seleccionadas
                        convertirAPDF(false);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Cancelar la acción
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void convertirAPDF(boolean convertirTodo){
    Log.d(TAG, "comvertirAPDF: convertirTodo: "+convertirTodo);

    progressDialog.setMessage("Convirtiendo a PDF...");
    progressDialog.show();

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Log.d(TAG, "run: Se inicia la tarea");

            ArrayList<ModelImage> listaImagenesPdf = new ArrayList<>();
            if(convertirTodo){
                listaImagenesPdf = imagenesArrayList;
            }else{
                // Sólo las imágenes seleccionadas
                for(int i=0; i < imagenesArrayList.size(); i++){
                    if(imagenesArrayList.get(i).isChecked()){
                        listaImagenesPdf.add(imagenesArrayList.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "run: Tamaño de la lista de imágenes a PDF:"+listaImagenesPdf.size());

            try{
                File root = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), Constantes.IMAGES_FOLDER);
                root.mkdirs();
                // Nombre con extensión de archivo
                long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                String nombreArchivo = "PDF_"+timestamp+".pdf";

                Log.d(TAG, "run: nombreArchivo: "+nombreArchivo);

                File file = new File(root, nombreArchivo);

                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();

                for(int i=0; i < listaImagenesPdf.size(); i++){

                    Uri imageToPDFUri = listaImagenesPdf.get(i).getImageUri();

                    try{

                        Bitmap bitmap;
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
                            bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(mContext.getContentResolver(), imageToPDFUri));
                        }else{

                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), imageToPDFUri);
                        }

                        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);

                        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), i+1).create();

                        PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);



                        Paint paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

                        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
                        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);

                        pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
                        bitmap.recycle();

                    }catch(Exception e){

                        Log.d(TAG, "run: ",e);
                    }
                }

                pdfDocument.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
                pdfDocument.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ",e);
            }

            //
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: Convertido...");

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Convertido...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void eliminarImagenes(boolean eliminarTodo){
    ArrayList<ModelImage> eliminarListaImagenes = new ArrayList<>();
    if(eliminarTodo){
        eliminarListaImagenes = imagenesArrayList;
    }else{
        // Elimina sólo las imágenes seleccionadas, las añade a la lista de imágenes eliminadas
        for(int i = 0; i<imagenesArrayList.size(); i++){

            // Comprueba si la imagen ha sido seleccionada o no
            if(imagenesArrayList.get(i).isChecked()){
                // Si ha sido seleccionada, se añade a la lista de imágenes eliminadas
                eliminarListaImagenes.add(imagenesArrayList.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<eliminarListaImagenes.size(); i++){

        try {
            String rutaImagenAEliminar = eliminarListaImagenes.get(i).getImageUri().getPath();

            File file = new File(rutaImagenAEliminar);
            if(file.exists()){
                // Elimina el archivo y devuelve el resultado como verdadero o falso
                boolean esEliminada = file.delete();
                // Se muestra en el Log
                Log.d(TAG, "eliminarImagen: esEliminada"+esEliminada);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "eliminarImagenes: ", e);
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Imagen/es eliminada/as", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    loadImages();
}
```

Alguna sugerencia de lo que podría hacer. para hacer visible esas dos opciones y volver a ocultarlas cuando se pulse el boton de retroceso. Gracias de antemano